ODI 12c Work Repository: Reusable Mapping Lineage
My team is trying to create a Data Lineage SQL query using the metadata tables from the ODI-12c work repository. The idea is to input a specific column into our query and return all the stages/transformations that column has undergone until the final output, or vice versa. At the moment, we have managed to build a basic query that considers every mapping within an ODI package, but this query fails when a 'ReusableMapping' component is present in our mappings. We have not been able to find a workaround for extracting the transformations performed in that reusable mapping.
The sql query we have is:
-- Define the user's input for the initial output column
DECLARE @UserOutputColumn NVARCHAR(255) = '<datastore.output_column>';
DECLARE @UserPackage NVARCHAR(255) = '<your_ODI_package>';

-- Create a CTE to precompute the necessary columns
WITH PrecomputedData AS (
    SELECT 
        map.I_MAPPING,
        STEP.NNO as MAPPING_ORDER,
        MAP.[NAME] as Mapping,
        CASE 
            WHEN ME.TXT IS NOT NULL THEN ME.TXT 
            ELSE CONCAT(MR.QUALIFIED_NAME, '.', MA.NAME)
        END as origin,
        mc.[NAME] as Component,
        mc.[TYPE_NAME] as Comp_Type,
        MA.[NAME] as OUTPUT_ATTRIBUTE,
        CASE 
            WHEN mc.TYPE_NAME = 'DATASTORE' AND ME.TXT IS NOT NULL AND MR.QUALIFIED_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(MR.QUALIFIED_NAME, '.', MA.NAME)
            ELSE CONCAT(mc.[NAME], '.', MA.[NAME]) 
        END as table_output
    FROM 
        [db_odiwork].[dbo].SNP_MAP_COMP mc
    JOIN 
        [db_odiwork].[dbo].SNP_MAPPING MAP ON mc.I_OWNER_MAPPING = MAP.I_MAPPING
    JOIN 
        [db_odiwork].[dbo].SNP_MAP_CP CP ON CP.I_OWNER_MAP_COMP = mc.I_MAP_COMP
    JOIN 
        [db_odiwork].[dbo].SNP_MAP_ATTR MA ON CP.I_MAP_CP = MA.I_OWNER_MAP_CP -- only 'Output' direction
    LEFT JOIN 
        [db_odiwork].[dbo].SNP_MAP_EXPR ME ON MA.I_MAP_ATTR = ME.I_OWNER_MAP_ATTR
    LEFT JOIN 
        [db_odiwork].dbo.SNP_MAP_REF MR ON mc.I_MAP_REF = MR.I_MAP_REF
    JOIN 
        [db_odiwork].[dbo].[SNP_FOLDER] folder ON map.I_FOLDER = folder.I_FOLDER
    JOIN
        [db_odiwork].[dbo].SNP_STEP STEP ON STEP.I_MAPPING = MAP.I_MAPPING
    JOIN 
        [db_odiwork].[dbo].SNP_PACKAGE package ON STEP.I_PACKAGE = package.I_PACKAGE
    WHERE 
        1=1
        -- AND I.NAME = '<COMP_NAME>'
        -- AND MAP.NAME LIKE '%142P031%'
        AND package.PACK_NAME LIKE @UserPackage
)

-- Recursive CTE to trace lineage
, LineageCTE AS (
    -- Anchor member: select the initial row based on the user-specified final column
    SELECT 
        I_MAPPING,
        MAPPING_ORDER,
        Mapping, 
        origin, 
        Component, 
        Comp_Type, 
        OUTPUT_ATTRIBUTE, 
        table_output,
        0 as LEVEL -- initial level
    FROM 
        PrecomputedData
    WHERE 
        table_output = @UserOutputColumn
    
    UNION ALL
    
    -- Recursive member: select the preceding rows based on the current origin
    SELECT 
        PC.I_MAPPING,
        pc.MAPPING_ORDER,
        pc.Mapping, 
        pc.origin, 
        pc.Component, 
        pc.Comp_Type, 
        pc.OUTPUT_ATTRIBUTE, 
        pc.table_output,
        cte.LEVEL + 1 -- increment level
    FROM 
        PrecomputedData pc
    INNER JOIN 
        LineageCTE cte ON cte.origin = pc.table_output AND cte.MAPPING_ORDER >= pc.MAPPING_ORDER
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    Mapping,
    origin, 
    CONCAT(Component, '(', Comp_Type, ')') AS COMPONENT,
    table_output,
    MAPPING_ORDER as MAPPING_STEP,
    LEVEL
FROM LineageCTE lineage
JOIN [db_odiwork].[dbo].SNP_STEP step ON step.I_MAPPING = lineage.I_MAPPING
ORDER BY MAPPING_STEP, LEVEL DESC, Mapping, Component;

This query works well for multiple mappings inside a package, considering the order of each mapping and of each mapping's component, and returning the complete lineage for a given output column (datastore.column) when:

The expression of each transformation is like <table.column>.
We consider simple transformations that manipulate columns, like AGGREGATE & DATASTORE.

So right now the problem is when we have a REUSABLEMAPPING component. We would want to 'enter' to that mapping, and continue with our lineage. For example:
enter image description here
Taking the 'SAL' column as our target column, we would want to get a lineage like this:



Mapping
origin
Component
Comp_Type
OUTPUT_ATTRIBUTE
table_output




Mapping1
DATASTORE.EXAMPLE.EMP.SAL
EMP
DATASTORE
SAL
EMP.SAL


REUSABLEMAPPING
EMP.SAL
FIRST_TRANSFORMATION
XXXXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX


...
...
...
...
...
...


REUSABLEMAPPING
XXXXXXX
LAST_TRANSFORMATION
XXXXXXXX
COMM_SAL
DATASTORE.REUSABLEMAPPING.LAST_TRANSFORMATION.COMM_SAL


Mapping1
DATASTORE.REUSABLEMAPPING.LAST_TRANSFORMATION.COMM_SAL
EMPLOEE_1
DATASTORE
SAL
DATASTORE. EXAMPLE.EMPLOEE_1.SAL



Easier, we would like to achieve something with this logic:
EMP.SAL ---> {SAL in REUSABLEMAPPING} ---> EMPLOEE_1.SAL

Any guidance or advice you can give us will be very much appreciate. Thank you all.
